# Accessing & Messaging DetailVC in a UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, delegation

I'm using a UISplitViewController that uses two UINavigationController's, one for MasterVC and another for the DetailVC. I'm trying to send messages to the DetailVC's topViewController from a VC in the MasterVC's navigation stack. This is how I'm accessing the receiving VC.

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController*)window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

DefaultDetailedViewController_iPad *defaultVC = (DefaultDetailedViewController_iPad*)navigationController.topViewController;

if ( [defaultVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MapDelegate)] ) {
    [defaultVC clearPreviousAnnotations];
}
```

The IF executes but the clearPreviousAnnotations does not get called. What's the best way to access and message the DetailVC?

I should also say that I'm a hobbyist and very much new to programming.

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

Well that was simple, I accessed it this way:

```
 RootViewController *rvc = (RootViewController*)[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[rvc.mapDelegate clearPreviousAnnotations];
```

Thank you guys again.

Comment: by if executes do you mean it gets to the if but it's returning false and skipping over the clearPreviousAnnotations line?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I mean. The code enters the IF, but defaultVC never executes clearPeviousAnnotations.